# Combining sentences and preposition usage

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence

**Edited after Yosef Baskin's suggestion:**

Assume that I wanted to combine all of these sentences into one, but ***strictly without*** using a semicolon or repeating the word "them":

"I'm intolerant of them. I'm strongly against them. I feel hate towards them."

Result:

"I am intolerant of, am strongly against, and feel hate towards them."

Is this okay? Can you put commas in front of preceding prepositions as long as the finishing preposition connects to the main subject ("them") and brings them all together?

Sorry if this seems like a random question, but I've been having difficulties with this.

Thanks kindly for any assistance.